# Unsure how to concatenate each numpy array within a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two lists that contain thousands of numpy arrays.

I would like to find an efficient way to concatenate each numpy array that is located at the same index.

For example:

```
list1 = [[0,0,2],[0,5,6]]
list2 = [[3,4,6],[1,7,8]]

final_list = [[0,0,2,0,5,6],[3,4,6,1,7,8]]
```

I need to do this for a list of size 3300.

Comment: You gave us a pure list example, but talk about lists of arrays.  Please be consistent.  A list answer will be different from a numpy array one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [np.array([0,0,2]),np.array([0,5,6])]
list2 = [np.array([3,4,6]),np.array([1,7,8])]

final_list = np.hstack((list1, list2))
print final_list
```